# Hide full path in gfortran run-time error messages

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am using the gfortran to compile a big program with a dozen of modules. Whenever there is an error in the code the program generates an error message with the line number where the error has happened and full path of the module that the line belongs to. For example:

```
At line 1775 of file C:\temp\test.f90 (Unit = 200, file=' ')
Fortran Run time error: File '*' does not exist
```

My question is how do you stop the program from listing the full path of the offending module and rather make it only report the module name where the error has happened.

Answer (score 1):

`gfortran` embeds the path that was used to access the source file during the compilation phase. E.g. if you compile with the full path to the file you will get the full path in the debug output. If you compile with the relative path you will get the relative path in the output:

```
~/tests[520]$ gfortran -o test.x test.f90
~/tests[521]$ test.x
At line 3 of file test.f90 (unit = 200, file = '')
Fortran runtime error: File '' does not exist

~/tests[522]$ gfortran -o test.x ./test.f90
~/tests[523]$ test.x
At line 3 of file ./test.f90 (unit = 200, file = '')
Fortran runtime error: File '' does not exist

~/tests[524]$ gfortran -o test.x ~/tests/test.f90
~/tests[525]$ test.x
At line 3 of file /home/username/tests/test.f90 (unit = 200, file = '')
Fortran runtime error: File '' does not exist
```

Change your compilation commands to only access the source using relative paths.

Comment: Thanks Hristo, but my program was compiled with Cmake and I didn't explicitly tell gfortran the location of my source files. Rather, I entered the source and bin folders into the Cmake GUI. The source files were part of the information entered into the Cmakelist.txt file. I don't know if there is an option in CMake GUI that you can set to make it pass relative path as opposed to full path.

Thanks
Abdinasir

Comment: Sorry, I've never used the Cmake GUI (didn't even know that it existed until now).